# Check grammar of user input

Tags: ios, uitextchecker

I am making an app that checks the user's English grammar and I wanted to know if there was a way of checking a string and correcting it if its grammar is incorrect. I know UITextChecker only corrects the words if they are wrong but not the grammar of the sentence. Are there any other methods to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need an API to help with this.  Apple does not provide a grammar checking API, but Grammarly has one, but they won't share for good reason.  But here is one trying to get started. [https://www.grammarbot.io/post/grammarly-api-developers](https://www.grammarbot.io) Maybe it can help and you can contribute to it.